# Could not find or load main class when importing Jar class

Tags: java, jar, runtime-error

I know this question has been asked many times, but the answers from the other posts did not solve my problem.

I'm new to Java and I tried working with Jar files which for some reason failed.

My situation: I have a `Test.jar` where I defined a class First. I have the following Assignment.java:

```
public class Assignment {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    First n = new First();
  }
}
```

I'm using JDK and I run the following command:

```
javac -cp "Test.jar" Assignment.java
```

So this works fine and the Assignment.class is created. So I run the command:

```
java -cp "Test.jar" Assignment
```

This time I get an error: `could not find or load main class Assignment`. However, this class is clearly there. All files are contained in the classpath, so I have no clue what is going wrong here.

Comment: Try `java -cp .;Test.jar Assignment`

Comment: your `Asignment` class it not containt in the Test.jar, so your classpath should be "Test.jar:." on a linux system.

Comment: Wauw that worked! Can you explain to my why that is?